# Gridview sorting C#

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, aspxgridview

I have a MSSQL DB, with lot of records. I have a column in my table with serial number (Auto generated). I am populating the DB in grid-view (C#), I want to sort the gridview based on this serial number column while the gridview loads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well why don't you pass already sorted data to gridview.just use order by clause in your sql query and pass the query results to gridview which will be already sorted.

**select * from tablename order by SerialNumber(Sql syntax)**

About the second solution u can use dataview class to sort data before passing to gridview

Comment: exactly. second solution is using some LINQ (or other expressions) to sort data, but your solution is good practice.